# How to get price sheet from Microsoft Partner Center API C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-partnercenter-java

I am trying to retrieve the price sheet from Partner Center API using App + user authentication, but to no avail.

I followed the example from Microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/developer/partner-center-authentication. The PartnerConsent app runs, but when i try signing in, i remain in a constant loop of having to enter my credentials.

I also tried this example here : https://www.postman.com/abhishekpurohit/workspace/abpuro-s-workspace/request/1996497-a2e29b78-8111-4b7c-a2dd-02fda661d5df. I able to get a code, but then i get 401, un authorized when i call the api for the price sheet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code i am tying is from this github : git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/Partner-Center-DotNet-Samples.git , I filled in the details in the web.config file, but after i run it , it is stuck in a loop of asking me to enter my credentials over and over again

Comment: in this way, your question won't attract anybody to answer it! try to put the code part that you think the problem is, because nobody will visit GitHub to solve it!

Comment: Ok Sir. Thank you